# JNA, Mapping and pointers references

Tags: java, api, pointers, dll, jna

I need to use DLL inside my Java application. DLL is exporting some set of functions, authors called it "Direct DLL API". I'm trying to define in java equivalent of following function declaration:

```
int XcCompress( HXCEEDCMP hComp, const BYTE* pcSource, DWORD dwSourceSize, BYTE** ppcCompressed, DWORD* pdwCompressedSize, BOOL bEndOfData );
```

Inside my interface that extends Library I declared it as follows:

```
int XcCompress(WString hComp, Pointer pcSource, int dwSourceSize, Pointer[] ppcCompressed, IntByReference pdwCompressedSize, boolean bEndOfData);
```

Problem is everytime I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

So basically I'm stuck at this point.

`HXCEEDCMP hComp` - is suppose to store handler to the function, and works fine as WString for init DLL / destroying DLL functions so I kept it like this.

The header reference "creature" is:

```
typedef HXCEEDCMP ( XCD_WINAPI *LPFNXCCREATEXCEEDCOMPRESSIONW )( const WCHAR* );
```

`const BYTE* pcSource` - is the source data for compression, inside my code I instantiate it this way:

```
private static Pointer setByteArrayPointer(String dataToCompress) {
  Pointer pointer = new Memory(1024);
  pointer.write(0, dataToCompress.getBytes(), 0, 
  dataToCompress.getBytes().length);

  return pointer;
}
```

`DWORD dwSourceSize` - for this im getting reserved Memory size in this way:

```
String testData = "ABCDABCDABCDAAD";
Pointer source = setByteArrayPointer(testData);

(int) ((Memory)source).size()
```

`BYTE** ppcCompressed` - function should populate ppcCompressed reference after work is done. I assume I made a mistake there, by doing it in this way:

```
Pointer[] compressed = {new Pointer(1024), new Pointer(1024)};
```

`DWORD* pdwCompressedSize` - returned by function size of compressed data. I map it in this way:

```
IntByReference intByReference = new IntByReference();
```

Not sure if it is good idea aswell..

`BOOL bEndOfData` - i need to set it to true.

So finally my method call, which returns an error looks like this:

```
xceedApiDll.XcCompress(handle, source, (int) ((Memory)source).size(), compressed, intByReference, true);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think the main problem is your use of `Pointer(1024)` for the compressed value.  Use `Memory(1024)` to allocate native memory.   Also `BOOL` in Windows maps to `int`. Any nonzero value is `true`.

Comment: Using Memory as array return exception at runtime `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported array argument type: class com.sun.jna.Memory`, looks like `Memory` cannot be used as an array. I used single object instead and mapped `BOOL` to `int` so my final method declaration looks as follow: `int XcCompress(WString hComp, Pointer pcSource, int dwSourceSize, Memory ppcCompressed, IntByReference pdwCompressedSize, int bEndOfData);` I got still the same error :(

Comment: The docs say that you need to initialize a handle to the XceedZip object first. This is the pointer that you must pass as the HXCEEDCMP argument: https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-zip-for-activex/webframe.html#DLL_API_Initialization_and_Instanciation.html

Comment: The `ppcCompressed` argument may just be a pointer to the memory block to which the compressed data is written to, i.e. `new PointerByReference(memory)`

Comment: @cubrr I was reading the docs and I initialized a handle, but I didn't show this inside code. `HXCEEDCMP` is a `WString` inside my Java code, despite that it works correctly for `XcDestroyXceedCompression` it is causing problems after passing it to `XcCompression` method. For quick test I passed null reference to `XcCompress hComp` and I dont have Invalid memory access no more. However I'm not sure if data returned by XcCompress / XcDecompress method is correct, looks like I'm getting some random values now.. I try to declare `HXCEEDCMP` as Pointer, and I agree with `PointerByReference`

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved the issue (thanks for comments guys). Maybe for someone using this library it will be useful:

In the end the main problem was with handler declaration and the ppcCompressed value.

I used the following solution which works fine for me:

Method declarations inside java interface:

```
int XcCompress(Pointer hComp, byte[] pcSource, int dwSourceSize, PointerByReference ppcCompressed, IntByReference pdwCompressedSize, int bEndOfData);
int XcUncompress(Pointer hComp, byte[] pcSource, int dwSourceSize, PointerByReference ppcUncompressed, IntByReference pdwUncompressedSize, int bEndOfdata);
```

Usage:

```
private static final XceedFunctions XCEED_DLL_API;

static {
    XCEED_DLL_API = Native.load("XceedZipX64", XceedFunctions.class);
}

private static final String TEST_DATA = "abcabcddd";

//Data pointers
private static Pointer compHandle;
private static byte[]  baSource = TEST_DATA.getBytes();
private static PointerByReference pbrCompressed = new PointerByReference();
private static PointerByReference pbrUncompressed = new PointerByReference();
private static IntByReference ibrCompressedSize = new IntByReference();
private static IntByReference ibrUncompressedSize = new IntByReference();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        boolean isSuccessfulInit = XCEED_DLL_API.XceedZipInitDLL();
        if(isSuccessfulInit) {
            compHandle = XCEED_DLL_API.XcCreateXceedCompressionW(new WString("YOUR_LICENCE_KEY_HERE"));
            int compressionResult = XCEED_DLL_API.XcCompress(compHandle, baSource, baSource.length, pbrCompressed, ibrCompressedSize, 1);
            byte[] compressed = getDataFromPbr(pbrCompressed, ibrCompressedSize);
            System.out.println("Compression result: " + compressionResult + " Data: " + new String(compressed));
            int decompressionResult = XCEED_DLL_API.XcUncompress(compHandle, compressed, compressed.length, pbrUncompressed, ibrUncompressedSize, 1);
            byte[] uncompressed = getDataFromPbr(pbrUncompressed, ibrUncompressedSize);
            System.out.println("Decompression result: " + decompressionResult + " Data: " + new String(uncompressed));
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Free memory and shutdown");
        if(compHandle != null) {
            XCEED_DLL_API.XcDestroyXceedCompression(compHandle);
        }
        XCEED_DLL_API.XceedZipShutdownDLL();
    }
}

private static byte[] getDataFromPbr(PointerByReference pbr, IntByReference ibr) {
    return pbr.getValue().getByteArray(0, ibr.getValue());
}
```

Example output:

> Compression result: 0 Data:  KLJNLJNII yK
>
> Decompression result: 0 Data: abcabcddd
>
> Free memory and shutdown